# Read a text file and create a 'Page' every 7 lines

Tags: java, arrays, file, text

How may I accomplish the task above? What I have been trying to do is separate the pages into different arrays but failed terribly.

Code by request (does not even close to work)

```
    int a = 1; int b = 5;
    File folder = new File("c:/files");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    String[] page1 = new String[7];
    String[] page2 = new String[7];
    String[] page3 = new String[7];
    String[] page4 = new String[7];
    String[] page5 = new String[7];
    String[] page6 = new String[7];
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i<listOfFiles.length; i++)
    {
        if(i>=0 && i <= 7)
        {
            page1[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        }
        else if(i>=8 && i<=15)
        {
            page2[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        }
        else if(i>=16 && i<=23)
        {
            page3[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        }
        else if(i>=24 && i<=31)
        {
            page4[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        }
        else if(i>=32 && i<=39)
        {
            page5[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

- [Read text file in java](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=read%20text%20file%20in%20java&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)
- Use the [modulo operator](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java%20modulo&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&hl=de&client=safari&rls=en&source=hp&q=modulus%20in%20for%20loop&pbx=1&oq=modulus%20in%20for%20loop&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=13940l16059l7l16203l9l8l2l0l0l2l279l1164l0.2.3l7l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=1c5254b4949f9638&biw=1029&bih=1022)

Answer (score 0):

Your code can't work, because when you do `page2[i] = xxx`, the variable named `i` should take a value between 0 and 6, and its value goes from 8 to 15.  The same for the other pages.  Even page1 will fail because the last index you use is 7, that is not in the range 0-6.

Try something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length; i++)
{
    if(i>=0 && i<7)
    {
        page1[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
    }
    else if(i>=7 && i<15)
    {
        page2[i-7] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
    }
    else if(i>=16 && i<23)
    {
        page3[i-16] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
    }
    ...
}
```

I hope you get the idea. Even this way your code is a little ugly to maintain, you should think about how to define only one bidimensional array, and to use the modulus (`%`) operator to access it in a simpler way and with less code.

The following code is untested, but I hope it guides you:

```
int NUM_PAGES = 7;
File folder = new File("c:/files");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

String[][] pages = new String[NUM_PAGES][listOfFiles.length/NUMPAGES];
for (int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    int currentPage = i % 7;
    int currentPosition = pages[currentPage].length;
    pages[currentPage][currentPosition] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
}
```

You can also use Java Collections that would simplify your code even more;

Comment: I knew that. That is why I asked for a new way to do it. I realized the error, and knew I need a different way.

Comment: Edited to add some code (probably buggy but you get the idea)